# How to control accumulation mode when using sequential GroupByKey? Or other idiomatic approach?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My task is equivalent to:

- given a stream of letters (each letter is associated with the author)
- build the low-latency histogram of ngrams within a fixed window,
- assuming that correct ngram consists of a sequence of letters from the **same** author.

My pipeline looks like:

```
| 'Extract and assign timestamps' >> Map(..)
| 'Extract author from message'   >> Map(..)
| 'Assign author as key'          >> Map(lambda x: (x.author, x))     # :(author,chr)
| 'Assign windows'                >> WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(5*60),
                                     trigger=Repeatedly(AfterAny(
                                         AfterCount(2),
                                         AfterWatermark())),
                                     accumulation_mode=ACCUMULATING)
| 'Group letters by author'       >> GroupByKey()                     # :(author,[chr])
| 'Extract many ngrams from every substring' >> ParDo(..)             # :[(author, ngram)]
| 'Re-key by ngrams'              >> Map(lambda x: (x.ngram, 1))      # :(ngram,1)
| 'Group again, now by ngrams'    >> GroupByKey()                     # :(ngram,[1])
| 'Sum ngrams counts'             >> Map(lambda x: (x[0], sum(x[1]))) # :(ngram,count)
| 'Re-key by window'              >> ParDo(..)                        # :(window, (ngram,count))
| 'Group within window'           >> GroupByKey                       # :(window, [(ngram,count)])
```

My goal is to receive a single output message for every two input messages such that output message summarizes ngram-statistics between: the start of the current 5-minute interval in event-time, and current moment in processing-time.

Without `AfterCount`-trigger, everything works well: each window only has a single pane. I get a single histogram-message for every 5-minutes in event-time.

This pipeline doesn't really work as intended with multiple panes per window, because I have 3 GBKs here and each gets triggered by panes, and does so **with accumulation**. For example:

- after first two characters come in (let's say `('a','author1')` and `('b','author1')`, panes trigger in all **GBK**s;
- I get an output message which correctly summarizes all ngrams seen so far, which may look like `('[0,300)', [('ab', 1)])`;
- now I have:

  - buffered characters in front of the first 'Group letters by word'-GBK: `('author1','a')` and `('author1','b')`);
  - a buffered ngram in front of the second 'Group again, now by ngrams'-GBK: `('ab',1)`; and
  - a buffered ngram-sum in front of the third 'Group within window'-GBK: `('[0,300)',('ab',1))`
- when two more characters come in: `('c','author1')` and `('d','author2')` all GBKs get retriggered with buffered things:

  - first GBK correctly processes full data so far: `('a','author1')`, `('b','author1')`, `('c','author1')`, `('d','author2')` and correctly emits: `('author1',['a','b','c'])` and `('author2',['d'])`
  - second GBK processes buffered `('ab',1,)` as well as newly emitted `('bc',1)` and re-emitted `('ab',1)` - and here duplication starts (and cascades on each pane of the same window).
- after four characters my summary-statistics-so-far is `('[0,300)',[('ab',2),('bc',1)])` while it should be `('[0,300)',[('ab',1),('bc',1)])`

Here are the ideas I have:

- Intuitively I want to switch from ACCUMULATING to DISCARDING after first GBK. I can't see if Apache Beam supports that.
- I can use a single GBK-by-window and do all intermediate grouping and map-reducing inside the custom transform, but that feels like abandoning the Apache Beam model;
- I can re-window after first GBK and switch to DISCARDING, but then I start to get lots of empty or incomplete output windows - in other words, that doesn't satisfy my requirements.

What's the appropriate solution for such pipeline? How can I accumulate before first GBK, but discard before both others - yet make sure that panes for all three GBKs close around the same data (or its derivative)?